# Is it okay to leave except EMPTY, when I print out trackback anyway? [Python 3.10]

Tags: python, except

I understand that it's usually not a good idea to leave "except" empty as errors will go unnoticed.

For example:

```
def test4():
    try:
        0/0
    except:
        pass
    print('PROGRAM CONTINUES!')
```

Output:

```
PROGRAM CONTINUES!
```

So my usual solution would be to add an exception after except, for example like this:

```
def test4():
    try:
        0/0
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'EXCEPTION: {e}')
    print('PROGRAM CONTINUES!')
```

Output:

```
EXCEPTION: division by zero
PROGRAM CONTINUES!
```

---

I've decided to use `traceback.print_exc()` to get more details about the exception, but now I don't even need to use `Exception as e` anymore:

```
def test3():
    try:
        0/0
    except:
        print('EXCEPTION:')
        traceback.print_exc()
    print('PROGRAM CONTINUES!')
```

Output:

```
EXCEPTION:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\<path>\tests.py", line 16, in test3      
    0/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
PROGRAM CONTINUES!
```

**Is it okay to leave `except:` like this?**

I can add `Exception` after that, but do I even have any reason to do that if I don't want to catch any specific exception anyway?

Comment: Unless it causes any syntax error or becomes an obstacle in whatever problem you are solving, it's okay to do that. There's no law that says that `except` should always have `Exception` in it. You won't get arrested for doing what you have done so don't worry.

Comment: A "bare `except`" is discouraged because beginners use it to trap the one exception they had in mind, but it can catch many others they didn't. Especially when paired with `pass` this is a recipe for bafflement, as we see all too often on SO. But your code reports every exception so that is not an issue. Doing this may not be all that useful in a production program because, for example if your exception is File not found, then the next bit of code that reads the file will fail. So you need a sensible response to each exception, and a bare exception is too broad for that.